# Rao-Blackwell for Minimum-Variance Unbiased Estimator

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimators, rao-blackwell, minimum-variance

> Let $X$ be an observation from a distribution with probability mass
>   function:$f(x;\theta) =
>  \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{|x|}(1-\theta)^{1-|x|}I_{\{-1,0,1\}}(x),
>  \, \theta \in (0,1).$ Use **Rao-Blackwell** theorem to find the
>   Minimum-Variance Unbiased Estimator (*MVUE*).

To begin with, the PMF can also be written as
$$
f(x;\theta) = I_{\{-1,0,1\}}(x) (1-\theta)\exp \left\{|x| \ln\left(\frac{\theta}{2(1-\theta)}\right)\right\}
$$
and therefore $f$ belongs to the **Exponential Family**. According to *Pitman-Koopman*, there exists a **sufficient function** for the parameter $\theta$.

Now, from **R-B**: $W = E[R = |x| \big| T]$ (where $R = |x|$ is an Unbiased estimator of $\theta$ and $T$ is a sufficient and complete function for $\theta$).

The problem I face is that I don't get  how we construct a $T$ which is sufficient and complete for $\theta$ and how does one use it to find an explicit formula for $W$. Can someone provide me with these two steps for finding the MVUE?

Comment: By Factorisation theorem, $|X|$ is sufficient (and complete since this is exponential family).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write out the sampling distribution for the statistic $|X|$.  It is an extremely simple and well-known distributional form.  Once you have found this, finding the MVUE should not present much problem.